# How to evaluate various parameters of scheduling algorithms

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, scheduler

I want to find various parameters like waiting time, turnaround time, throughput of various processes under different scheduling algorithms in Linux.

Currently, I know how to find the current scheduling algorithm (using chrt     command) and the CPU utilization of various processes (using top command). It would be great if anyone can guide on how to proceed in this case. Also references to some other posts will be great.

Comment: These parameters are dependent on workload you running. So you should pick workload, use workload generator to simulate it and measure that parameters.